# Нарушает ли добавление метода по умолчанию в новый интерфейс какие-либо принципы проектирования?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

В Java 8+ добавлены методы по умолчанию для возможности развития существующих интерфейсов.

Нарушает ли добавление метода по умолчанию, сразу при создании интерфейса, какие-либо принципы проектирования? Стоит ли этого избегать?

Comment: Если инструмент позволяет реализовать задуманное более простым и рациональным способом, то его можно и нужно использовать. Если нет, то никто не заставляет. А если думать о том, не нарушу ли я какие то искусственные рамки и шаблоны, то можно идти в армию работать, там таких любят. Это я к тому, что вы пишите код и вам решать, какие принципы в него заложены

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это вполне нормальное использование метода по-умолчанию.

Метод по-умолчанию дает возможность объявить в интерфейсе метод, который необязательно будет нужно переопределять. Разработчики спецификации изначально рассматривали это как один из нормальных сценариев использования методов по-умолчанию.

Да, основной целью методов по-умолчанию было расширение имеющихся интерфейсов, но это не значит, что их нужно использовать только для этого.

Можете почитать ответ [Стюарта Маркса](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) на английском Stack Overflow: [Java default interface methods concrete use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661433/java-default-interface-methods-concrete-use-cases). В нем описываются всевозможные сценарии использования для методов по-умолчанию:

> **Optional Methods**
> Sometimes interface methods are logically "optional". Consider mutator methods on immutable collections, for example. Of course, an implementation is required, but usually what it will do in such cases is to throw an exception. This can easily be done in a default method. Implementations can inherit the exception-throwing method if they don't want to provide it, or they can override it if they want to provide an implementation.
> Example: `Iterator.remove`.
>
> **Необязательные методы**
> Иногда методы интерфейса с логической точки зрения «необязательны». Для примера рассмотрите методы, изменяющие коллекцию, для неизменяемых коллекий. Конечно, их нужно реализовать, но обычно реализованный метод выбрасывает исключение. Это можно легко прописать в методе по-умолчанию. Реализации унаследуют методы, выбрасывающие исключение, если они не хотят их переобпределять, либо переопределят их если нужна своя реализация.
> Пример: `Iterator.remove`.

Метод [`Iterator.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) хороший пример. Он уже существовал в [JDK 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()), но в JDK 8 был объявлен как default. Это сделано не для расширения возможностей, а для того чтобы наследники не реализовывали лишний метод, который им не нужен.

Также можете посмотреть презентацию Стюарта Маркса и Брайана Гетца на Java One ([слайды](https://stuartmarks.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/con6851-api-design-v2.pdf), [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=24m&v=o10ETyiNIsM&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=Java))